# Angular fields not displaying validation failed messages

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I have the following in a jade template

```
.row
             .col-lg-2
                label(for='AcctNumber') 
                   font(size="2") A
             .col-lg-8
                input(ng-model='form.acctNumber', name='acctNumber', id='acctNumber', on-focus="fieldInfo='Please enter your Acct Number'", required='true', ng-minlength='5', ng-maxlength='10')
             .col-lg-2
                div(ng-show="acctNumber.$error.required",style="color: red")
                   {{acctNumber.$error.required}}
                <span class="error" ng-show="acctNumber.$error.required">Required!</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="acctNumber.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="acctNumber.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
```

Required, Too long. Too short. None of the messages are displaying.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Melroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-show attribute for validation messages has this pattern "fieldName.$error.key". It should be "formName.fieldName.$error.key"

Comment: Thanks this worked. I was not using any forms and getting by but I did add the form element.